# Android Studio 2.2 Gradle update fails

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[New Android Studio](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/09/android-studio-2-2.html) ask me about Gradle plugin update

[image]

But it fails, when I press Update button.
Failed to update the version of Android Gradle Plugin

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's an inner bug of Android Studio

I just change manually

```
compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

in root `build.gradle` to

```
compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
```

And all started working.

Answer (score 0):

Download gradle this link manually and copy gradle folder

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Last version :

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-all.zip

[image]